# SSIS OLE DB Command error: Could not deduce type for parameter in position '1' for remote call to module 'sp_executesql'

Tags: sql, ssis, oledbcommand, sp-executesql

I have an OLE DB Command task in an SSIS package that received parameters, inserts them into a table in a linked-server, and returns the ID that was created on the linked server.

When I run the query in SSMS it works, but within SSIS I get the error message in the suject line.

The SqlCommand within the OLE DB Command is:

```
DECLARE
    @UserId int = ?,
    @ContactUsId int = ?,
    @CreateDate datetime = ?,
    @Subject nvarchar(500) = ?,
    @InteractionClusterId int = null  -- We will be testing for this being null

-- removed some irrelevant code here

-- if all else failed, insert a new record to MngInteractionCluster
if @InteractionClusterId is null
begin
    declare @RemoteQuery nvarchar(max) = N'
    insert into BI_Mng.dbo.MngInteractionCluster
    (
        UserId,
        ContactUsId,
        CreateDateTime,
        [Subject] 
    )
    values
    (
        @UserId,
        @ContactUsId,
        @CreateDate,
        @Subject
    )
  SELECT @InteractionClusterId_OUT = SCOPE_IDENTITY()'

    declare @Params nvarchar(1000)  = N'
        @UserId int,
        @ContactUsId int,
        @CreateDate datetime,
        @Subject nvarchar(500),
        @InteractionClusterId_OUT int OUTPUT'

    EXEC [BI_WAREHOUSE\BI_GLOBAL].master.dbo.sp_executesql
        @RemoteQuery,
        @Params,
        @UserId = @UserId ,
        @ContactUsId = @ContactUsId,
        @CreateDate = @CreateDate,
        @Subject = @Subject,
        @InteractionClusterId_OUT = @InteractionClusterId OUTPUT;

end

select
    ? = @InteractionClusterId
```

Any help on getting this to parse in SSIS would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up moving the heavy lifting into a stored procedure on the local server.
Now the code in the OLE DB command component is a concise

```
DECLARE
    @OriginalMailId int = ?,
    @UserId int = ?,
    @ContactUsId int = ?,
    @CreateDate datetime = ?,
    @Subject nvarchar(500) = ?,
    @isAutoReply bit = ?,
    @BIEnvironmentId int = ?,
    @InteractionClusterId int

exec BI_Mng.dbo.GetInteractionClusterId
    @OriginalMailId,
    @UserId,
    @ContactUsId,
    @CreateDate,
    @Subject,
    @isAutoReply,
    @BIEnvironmentId,
    @InteractionClusterId OUTPUT

select ? = @InteractionClusterId
```

Inside the stored procedure there's a call to a remote execution of sp_ExecuteSQL on the linked server. In order for SSIS to parse it, it's vital that it include a WITH RESULT SETS clause, like so:

```
declare @RemoteQuery nvarchar(max) = N'
insert into BI_Mng.dbo.MngInteractionCluster
(
UserId,
ContactUsId,
CreateDateTime,
[Subject] 
)
values
(
@UserId,
@ContactUsId,
@CreateDate,
@Subject
)
SELECT @InteractionClusterId_OUT = SCOPE_IDENTITY()'

declare @Params nvarchar(1000)  = N'
@UserId int,
@ContactUsId int,
@CreateDate datetime,
@Subject nvarchar(500),
@InteractionClusterId_OUT int OUTPUT'

EXEC [BI_WAREHOUSE\BI_GLOBAL].master.dbo.sp_executesql
@RemoteQuery,
@Params,
@UserId = @UserId ,
@ContactUsId = @ContactUsId,
@CreateDate = @CreateDate,
@Subject = @Subject,
@InteractionClusterId_OUT = @InteractionClusterId OUTPUT
WITH RESULT SETS NONE;
```